# Checkbox not working for non-repeated array javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone one help me make this work:

I have a Checkbox for a non-repeated array. If checkbox is checked to remove duplicates it  works fine, but if I uncheck `remove duplicates`, the checkbox still removes duplicates.

I want to make it work in such a way that if (remove duplicates) checkbox is not checked, extract all emails without removing duplicates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just a couple lines off... when you go to output the emails you need to check for the field that determines if you should use all the emails or the unique (not repeated) emails:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function findEmail() {
    var email = "No email address detected"; 
    var a = 0; 
    var ingroup = 0; 
    var separator = document.extractor.sep.value; 
    var groupby = Math.round(document.extractor.groupby.value);
    var outputEmails = [];

    if (separator == "new") separator = "\n"; 
    if (separator == "other") separator = document.extractor.othersep.value; 
    //match the email pattern in large text pasted in textarea. 
    var rawemail = document.extractor.rawdata.value.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);

    var norepeat = new Array(); 
    if (rawemail) {
        for (var i=0; i<rawemail.length; i++) {
            var repeat = 0; 

            // Check for repeated emails routine 
            for (var j=i+1; j<rawemail.length; j++) {
                if (rawemail[i] == rawemail[j]) {
                    repeat++;
                }
            } 

            // Create new array for non-repeated emails 
            if (repeat == 0) { 
                norepeat[a] = rawemail[i]; 
                a++; 
            } 
        } 

        // For output, use all or unique (non-repeated) emails?
        outputEmails = document.extractor["non-repeated"].checked ? norepeat : rawemail;
        if( document.extractor["sortbox"].checked ) {
            outputEmails = outputEmails.sort();
        }
        email = ""; 
        // Join emails together with separator 
        for (var k = 0; k < outputEmails.length; k++) {
            if (ingroup != 0) email += separator; 
            email += outputEmails[k]; 
            ingroup++; 

            // Group emails if a number is specified in form. Each group will be separate by new line. 
            if (groupby) {
                if (ingroup == groupby) { 
                    email += '\n\n'; 
                    ingroup = 0; 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }

    // Return array length 
    var count = norepeat.length; 

    // Print results 
    document.extractor.count.value = count; 
    document.extractor.rawdata.value = email; 
} 
</script>
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/jimbo2150/ucvLtsts/21/

Comment: thanks for answer ,but it doesn't work  ,in your jsfiddle eg it still remove duplicate emails even if we uncheck "Remove Duplicates" checkbox

Comment: It works for me - are you sure you are not hitting reset first? You have it setup to re-check that box when you press reset.

Comment: now dosen't work Checkbox for" Sort Alphabetically" even if "Sort Alphabeticaly" Checkbox is not checked the checkbox still sort alphabeticaly,before Sort Alphabeticaly worked fine,pleas can you take a look in your jsfiddle e g ,why?

Comment: hahaha thank you jim for your help sooo much its works like a charm now thnks